# java string split is not giving expected result

Tags: java, split, arrays

I'm trying to split a string into a string [] but im not getting the expected result. 
What is wrong here?

```
    String animals = "dog|cat|bear|elephant|giraffe";
    String[] animalsArray = animals.split("|");
```

I would expect that animalsArray contained the following:

```
    animalsArray[0] = "dog"
    animalsArray[1] = "cat"
    animalsArray[2] = "bear"
    ...
```

but it contains only:

```
    animalsArray[0] = "d"
    animalsArray[1] = "c"
    animalsArray[2] = "b"
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split()`splits around a regular expression, not just an ordinary string so you have to escape the "|" (because it has special meaning) and do it as follows:

```
split("\\|")
```

Comment: I suggest everyone leaves the edit alone until they've tried it out and verify it works. I've seen 3 different versions of it in less than a minute, and only one applied the code makeup.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Fixed for real now. :)

Comment: Btw, for more complicated strings that you want to treat as normal strings (not regular expressions), take a look at [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3):

The `split` method takes a regular expression as its argument, and `|` has special meaning.  Escape it with a backslash, and escape the backslash itself for Java:

```
String[] animalsArray = animals.split("\\|");
```

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) lists special symbols in Java regular expressions.  Look for `|` in the "Logical Operators" section.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try using **`\\|`**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String animals = "dog|cat|bear|elephant|giraffe";
    String[] animalsArray = animals.split("\\|");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animalsArray));
}
}
```

Output in Console:

```
[dog, cat, bear, elephant, giraffe]
```